# Inkscape Latex renderer fontsize doesn't match text

Tags: latex, inkscape

I want to render Latex equations in my Inkscape drawing with *Extensions → Render → Latex*. I want to render them directly at a specific fontsize for consistency and to match the fontsize to the figure dimensions.

The problem: The Latex output is way larger than the native Inkscape text (see image). Both are set to 8pt.

Question: How can I get consistent fontsize between native text and Latex text/equations?

[image]

Comment: As an alternative, modify the size of the object (in the same way you change the size of a rectangle).